# SQL Expression to find Values that start with Numbers 38

Tags: sql, expression

I have a table with column "paird" that is a 15 digit interger.
I need a SQL expression to find all the rows that paird starts with "38"

I tired the following but it failed

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE paird LIKE "38%"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: What exactly failed? Are you getting the wrong results? An error?

Comment: it looks like big integer value, does all values have 15 digits or it varies?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying works with strings. If you have a 15 digit integer column (and it is always 15 digits), you could try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE floor(paird/10000000000000) = 38;
```

Answer (score 2):

if i correct understand you, your problem is double quotes ", you need to replace on this one '

expl

select * from Table1 where Id like '1%' when i write "1%" i got the error

UPD. i try with long id and string still work in both ways

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert number to string first before using the LIKE operator.
See below for the example using sql-server:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    LTRIM(STR(Paired, 15, 0)) LIKE '38%'
```